# Lévy–Khintchine representation for distributions

Tags: levy-processes

I have read that the Lévy–Khintchine representation exists for any infinitely divisible distribution. However, all the references I could find on Lévy–Khintchine representations are for Lévy processes.
But how to derive the Lévy–Khintchine representation for a distribution, such as the Gamma distribution (not process)?

Comment: There is a one-to-one correspondence between infinitely divisible distributions and Levy processes.  The Gamma distribution, for example, is the marginal of $X_{1}$, if $X$ is the Gamma process.  See Proposition 2.1 here: http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/385/LevyProcesses.pdf
At any rate, the Levy-Kintchine representation for distributions is proved in Varadhan's book titled Probability Theory, if you have access to a library.